# How does npm know the path to install module from

Tags: node.js, npm, dependencies

I am new to npm, using package.json to define the dependencies. I am just curious where is those dependencies installed from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, npm checks your local machine for packages installed globally, or using the `-g` flag.

ie: if you used `npm install -g moduleName`

You can run `npm list -g` to figure out where that is on your machine.
Otherwise, npm goes to where you set the npm registry. By default this is [npmjs](https://www.npmjs.com/).

If you want to see the default settings, run `npm config list`